# Is it possible to deploy both the iphone and ipad *.ipa to the Application Center?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I am able to build both the iphone and ipad ipa files (app.ipa and app-ipad.ipa) fine. However, when I go to deploy them to the Application Center via the native-deployer api,
the Application Center only shows one app of type "ios", where I expect two apps, one for iphone and one for ipad.

Since this is one worklight project. The application-descriptor is the same. The version number and bundle ids are exactly the same. What do I need to change to differentiate them?
I think if the bundle id is different Application Center will discern them, for sure. But worklight did not change the bundle id when I added the environment, so I left them unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bundleId` value in application-descriptor.xml for the iPad and iPhone environments is merely a placeholder. Obviously, you need to change it.

You can change it either in application-descriptor.xml, in which case it will be pre-set by the time you open the generated Xcode project in Xcode. Or you can set it when you open the project in Xcode.

The simplest way is to just set it in application-descriptor.xml...

Note that Worklight has got nothing to do with your iOS app once it is generated and you want  to release it. Any and all configurations are then mostly related to Xcode settings of your application. Read more here:

- [Configuring Your Xcode Project for Distribution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html)

---

Another thing to note is that a Worklight-based iOS app, be it the iPhone or iPad environment is configured as a Universal app by default (fit for both iPhone and iPad). Perhaps what is missing in your case is to differentiate the two.

- In Xode, for each project (iPhone and iPad), look for the setting to set it as an iPhone or iPad app, rather than Universal app.
- Then, try uploading to the Application Center management console again and check if you are now able to see TWO apps.

[image]